# What are the fee used for? Who receives the fee for UniswapV3 ExactInputSingleParams

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv3

Why do we need the fee?
Isn't it specified that Uniswap will charge 0.30%?
Why do we need to specify a fee here and to who?
Can we set the fee to 0?

```
    struct ExactInputSingleParams {
        address tokenIn;
        address tokenOut;
        uint24 fee; // Who receives the fee?
        address recipient;
        uint256 deadline;
        uint256 amountIn;
        uint256 amountOutMinimum;
        uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96;
    }
```